Use Tax Legitimacy
I recently learned of Use Tax.
The use tax I learned about is a little different than that defined above in that it is a small town enforcing a tax on goods purchased elsewhere, even though a sales tax is applied in the other location. I am flabbergasted that this is legal/constitutional.
Has there ever been any legal challenges to this?
Edit:
So I get the there can be a tax for each level of govt, i.e. if you buy something you may pay tax for the local municipality, the state, the fed. What seems wrong to me is that a local municipality charges a use tax if you buy stuff in another municipality.
In this case, when getting a building permit in say, Springfield but buying concrete blocks in Shelbyville, Springfield levies a use tax in the permit. And what is worse, the use tax is levied even if concrete blocks are not available in Springfield.

My impression is that most use taxes allow you to claim a credit for any sales tax paid to other jurisdictions.  For example, if a resident of Connecticut (sales tax 6.35%) buys a flat-screen TV in Massachusetts (sales tax 6.25%), they would only have to pay the additional 0.1% to Connecticut.  Are there cases you can cite where these credits don't exist?  Or does it seem to you that because a tax was imposed elsewhere, no tax should be imposed in Connecticut?

(Not judging either way, just trying to gauge what points need to be addressed in a potential answer.)

What town? It's definitely constitutional (sales tax has always been allowed and is charged locally, not by the Federal government), but you might want to consider asking whether that specific town is acting correctly per the State law. As a general rule, double taxation is a real thing, and absent specific laws and treaties requiring credits as @MichaelSeifert suggests, it will happen (and happens quite often with other taxes - income, social security, payroll, etc).

@MichaelHall because you, as the buyer, have a legal duty to tell them.

@MichaelHall I an in Australia where all forms of customs and duties (which includes sales taxes, use taxes, and value added taxes) can only be levied by the Federal government because of the way our constitution is drafted. But, we have a similar issue where taxpayers are required to levy GST and emit it on purchases from outside Australia valued at over a certain amount (about $1,000). This works about as well as you’d expect in these days of frictionless international e-commerce.

Is there a particular provision of the Constitution that you think it might violate? I can't think of any.

In fact, its a use tax versus sales tax to get around the Interstate Commerce Clause.

Added comment above for clarification and griping.

@MichaelHall "My town does not have such a requirement": because, not having a use tax, it has no need to enact one.  Jurisdictions that do have use tax, by contrast, will normally do so.
In other words, it's not a universal obligation; it's a jurisdiction-specific obligation imposed by jurisdictions that have a use tax.  I suppose there are not many taxes in the world that do not come with a legal obligation to declare relevant facts, even if many such obligations are almost never enforced and are virtually unenforceable.

@AlLelopath which Springfield?

The US Constitution does not address state and local taxation
ArtI.S8.C1.1.1 gives the Federal government the power to levy taxes, but it does not restrict or interfere with the power of states (including any sub-state governments they empower) to do so.
State law
The starting point for this analysis is that, unless a state has deliberately restricted itself, it has to power to levy any sort of tax that it wants. County and city governments are creations of state law, and they have the power to levy whatever taxes the state delegates to them.
So, assuming that the state has not banned use taxes, and assuming the municipality has legally enacted the relevant ordinance, there is no legal impediment to such a tax.
While I don’t know of any case challenging use taxes, SOUTH DAKOTA v. WAYFAIR, INC., ET AL. USSC No. 17–494 2018 takes them as a given without remarking on them.
However, not all taxes are practical due to being inefficient, inequitable, or difficult to enforce. Use taxes are difficult to enforce as they rely on the user paying the tax themselves and non-compliance is difficult if not impossible to detect. Income tax for non-wage earners suffers the same problem; particularly for taxpayers who operate predominantly in cash.

This answer is preposterously ill-informed. Wouldn't it make better sense to just not answer a question one doesn't have any meaningful expertise in, rather than just taking blind guesses about how a nation's constitution works?

Yes, I spent about a decade reading about state use taxes on a near-daily basis. I think, though, that we're talking about different kinds of reading. Scanning the Constitution and failing to find an explicit mention of state use taxes doesn't really confer any actual understanding of how they work or how the Constitution constrains them.

@bdb484 for those of us who haven't put in the years of study on use taxes, it would be helpful if you could describe the errors you find in this answer rather than simply criticizing it as "ill informed" -- or write your own answer and let the voting buttons do what they're supposed to.

@phoog I get where you're coming from, but there's not always time for that. If there's a narrow error, I'll upvote and leave a comment addressing the issue, but if the answer is completely uninformed, there may be time to downvote, but not time to walk someone through all the ways they're wrong. If that's the case, I think a comment warning people away from believing completely wrong information is the next best option.

Even though there's nothing in the Constitution about it, couldn't the federal government make laws regarding taxation on interstate commerce?
